# Infinite loop on sets folding

Tags: java, set, infinite-loop

I have a task to remove any set from the collection that is wholy included into some other set:

```
private static Set<Set<String>> foldSets(Set<Set<String>> sets) {
    OUTER:
    while (true) {
        for (Set<String> s1 : sets) {
            Set<Set<String>> toRemove = new HashSet<>();
            for (Set<String> s2 : sets) {
                if (s1.size() > s2.size() && s1.containsAll(s2)) {
                    toRemove.add(s2);
                }
            }
            if (!toRemove.isEmpty()) {
                sets.removeAll(toRemove);
                continue OUTER;
            }
        }
        return sets;
    }
}
```

*OUTER* loop goes infinite, while common sense tells me it's impossible under any circumstances. That happens because *removeAll* method doesn't remove anything from sets.

This riddle drives me crazy. Please, help to solve.

Similar problem: [Why won't it remove from the set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1086595/1065145)

Comment: Did you do a step by step debugging? Which step did not make sense to you?

Comment: @user1803551 Please, see the answer. Contol flow is ok, set is "broken" though.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a permission problem.

If you Overrided it, it would be good to see your "removeAll" method, anyways. You are trying to delete folders, right?

If you can't solve it I have a working code that recursively removes folders and files inside it.

[Here](https://github.com/helicida/Example_Files/blob/master/src/BorrarCarpeta_Recursivitat/BorrarCarpeta.java) is the sample.

If you are not deleting folders and it's just a String stuff debug it and tell us which step is not working at all.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it's just sets of strings.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

It was a hash problem. Sets added to *sets* were modified after adding. That rendered them invisible for *removeAll* method, which relies on *hash* to lookup items.

Quite a riddle, nevertheless.